# JS URI encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, uri

I have problem with URI encoding charset
My JS code (AJAX) uses encodeURIcomponent() 
It uses UTF-8.
Server reads it as it was Windows-1251 (ISS server with classic ASP)
If I edit e string in JS replacing encoded % value using this table :
[ASCII Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
fron UTF-8 to Windows-1251 it works fine.

I tryed:
request.setcharacterencodeing  -not supported
web.config  - no change

Comment: IIS server not ISS :)

Comment: You can try to change the charset of the webpage (using meta-tag) or try to make IIS using UTF-8

Comment: If I change webpage  charset it doesn't change result of the encodeURIcomponent()
I don't know how to change IIS. <globalization> seems to not work or I am doing sth wrong...